# Wrap two variables into a wrapper class in java

Tags: java

I am doing leetcode Q 230.
The problem is
**Given a binary search tree, write a function kthSmallest to find the kth smallest element in it.**
I googled one solution to this problem, the solution mentions that it might be good to wrap two variables into a wrapper class.  I don't know how to wrapper the two variables (number & count) in a wrapper class and what is the good use of it?  I know that Integer is the wrapper class of int.

```
***better keep these two variables in a wrapper class***

private static int number = 0;
private static int count = 0;

public int kthSmallest(TreeNode root, int k) {
    count = k;
    helper(root);
    return number;
}

public void helper(TreeNode n) {
    if (n.left != null) helper(n.left);
    count--;
    if (count == 0) {
        number = n.val;
        return;
    }
    if (n.right != null) helper(n.right);
}
```

Comment: Your question would be clearer to see where these methods are called...

Comment: Im pretty sure they meam just to have simple java class with 2 fields number &  count

Comment: Thanks for the reply but leetcode does not provide the the caller.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how to wrapper the two variables (number & count) in a wrapper class

You need to create a self-defined class with `count` and `number` as field, something like:

```
class KthSmallestElementWrapper<T> {
private int kth;
private T result;

public KthSmallestElementWrapper(int kth) {
    this.kth = kth;
}

public static KthSmallestElementWrapper of(int kth) {
    return new KthSmallestElementWrapper(kth);
}

public boolean isDone() {
    return kth == 0;
}

public T getResult() {
    if (result == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Result not found");
    }
    return result;
}

public void decreaseCount() {
    kth--;
}

public void setResult(T t) {
    this.result = t;
}
}
```

> what is the good use of it?

In addition to the way LeeCode execute the submitted code, creating a wrapper class is good for encapsulation. As the code above, you can encapsulate `counter` and `result` into one class, and some necessary methods like test method `isDone` and method `decreaseCount`.

BTW, did you test your `helper` method? It's a recursive method but I don't think the termination condition is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The strategy there is that LeetCode (and most online programming sites) executes any code you type within its own class.

Having `static` variables there will keep them in scope of that class and therefore, it is not necessary to pass them around between your own methods.

The "wrapper class" is hidden

---

You could also do this yourself

```
class Wrapper {
    public static int number, count;
}
```

And access `Wrapper.number` and `Wrapper.count`

Comment: I found it that when i tried to pass the variable into the method, the solution is wrong.

Comment: That would be a logically mistake, then

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I found that basically there is no difference between setting the variable as static and wrapping the variables into the class.  So why wrapping the variable into the a class is better?

Comment: The variables are in a class regardless. The real question is whether you have them locally within a method where they are reset when you exit the method, or kept scoped across the entire class.